# Jenkins: How to show/hide string parameter fields, after checkbox is un/checked?

Tags: checkbox, jenkins, show, optional-parameters

I need to create Jenkins job, which installs product.iso on defined machine.
I have 2 options:
latest.iso (path to it is already known)
custom.iso (path have to be determined manually)

Best implementation would be for me a checkbox named: "install custom iso"

When user choose(check) this checkbox
- two string parameter fields would appear below (for determine IP and PATH of custom iso.)
When user unchecks this checkbox
- these two string parameter fields disappear (and default latest.iso would be installed)

I've searched through many Jenkins plugins, but it seems, that none of them allows this kind of action, which is strange to me, because I think, that this type of action is frequently needed.

Is there any simple way to do it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use a parameterized build but this won't hide unneeded input fields.

Comment: Now it is made, using parameters. But these string parameters fields are visible even when custom checkbox is not checked, and it is confusing for users.

Comment: [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) provides what you need.

Comment: "Active Choices Plugin" is able to update parameters based on another parameter, however, it is unable to "hide" a parameter like javascript. That's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think this Plugin will help you to make your Parametarized build more dynamic.

> The **Active Choices plug-in** provides additional Jenkins parameter types
> that can be rendered as user interface (UI) controls in job forms. It
> supports using system environment variables, global node properties,
> and you also have at least the Jenkins project in the Groovy context
> for Freestyle jobs at least.
>
> Once the plugin is installed three new parameter types become
> available:
>
> 1. Active Choices Parameter
> 2. Active Choices Reactive Parameter
> 3. Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter
>
> Active Choices parameters allow
> users to select value(s) for a job parameter. Parameter values can be:
>
> a) dynamically generated (using Groovy or a Scriptler script)
>
> b) dynamically
> updated based on other UI parameters
>
> c) multi-valued (can have more than
> one value)
>
> d) rendered with a variety of UI controls, including dynamic
> HTML.

For more clarification and examples, Please refer here: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin